# empty .sql file on mysqldump

Tags: mysql, sql, database, backup

i'm trying to create a backup from my MySQL database and when I execute the following code, I always get an empty file inside my .gz:

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbName = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$pathToBackupDirectory = "folderSecurity";
$project = "test";
$backup_file = "$pathToBackupDirectory/$project-" . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . ".sql.gz";
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $host -u $username -p $password $dbName | gzip > $backup_file";
exec($command);
```

(I'm doing it on localhost right now, testing before upload on production. Running on a MAMP).